# Verify that $x\mapsto (\cos(x),\sin(x))$ from the real line to the unit circle is an open map.

Tags: general-topology

**The setup:**

Let $p:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ be defined by $x\mapsto (\cos(x),\sin(x))$. Prove that $p$ is open, i.e. $p$ sends open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ to open subsets of $S^1=\{ (\cos(x),\sin(x))\in \mathbb{R}^2 \ \vert \ x\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

**What I have so far:**

Since the image of maps preserves unions, it suffices to check on basic open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. open intervals. If such an interval has length no less than $2\pi$, then its image under $p$ is the whole circle, which is open.

On the other hand, if the interval has length less than $2\pi$, then its image is an "open arc" on $S^1$, which can be realized as an intersection of $S^1$ with an appropriately chosen open box of $\mathbb{R}^2$, as illustrated below.

[image: circle and box]

**My question:**

> How can I formalize this last bit, so as to avoid arguing from a figure only? My current attempts at constructing the desired box precisely have relied on checking cases. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: It's enough to show that your map is a local homeomorphism - that might be easier since you just have to define a local inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I$ be an open set of $\Bbb R$. Then the set $O=\{ r(\cos x, \sin x) \ , \ r>0 ; x\in I \}$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$ , we have

$p(I)=O\cap S^1$ open subset of $S^1$.

**EDIT: $O$ is open:** Let $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ defined by $f(r,x)=r(\cos x,\sin x)$ it is clear that $f$ is continuous , since $\Bbb R_+^*\times I$ is an open of $\Bbb R^2$ (product of two open) then $O=f^{-1}(\Bbb R_+^*\times I)$ is open of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: See the edit for $O$ open.

Comment: $O=f(\mathbb{R}^*_+ \times I)$ not $f^{-1}$

Comment: @Minato Indeed. In this case the answer has to explain why $f$ is an open map (if so).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Open arc can be broken up into the union of "small" open arcs. Such small that each one can easily be represented in your way.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose that $f: M\to N$ is a smooth map of smooth manifolds, such that the derivative $df: T_xM\to T_yN$ is surjective for all $x\in M$ ($y=f(x)$). Then $f$ is a submersion and, hence, an open map. For equidimensional manifolds, like in you case, you can, alternatively, verify that $df$ is injective at each point. Now, compute the derivative of your map ...

Comment: This is borderline ridiculous! =) (Of course, it is a valid generalization, but if one cannot prove by hand that $t\mapsto e^{it}$ is open, then one will be using the tool above blindly, not knowing what is going on.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Dear Pedro, I like giving ridiculous answers (I think you should have omitted "borderline"), you will probably enjoy another one here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295371/a-simply-connected-closed-surface-is-a-sphere/1799361#1799361.